# 'Outliers' in a data set

Tags: r

I have to use R to analyse a large dataset of ratings from 0 to 10, but the data has the number 99 if the answer is "don't know". When I am trying to analyse the central tendency and dispersion, having these 99s is clearly going to mess up my calculation. I am wondering if there is a good way to get rid of these 99s?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is easier to google than to ask stack overflow. But since were are all here...

How about `na_if`

```
dplyr::na_if(c(1,2,5,4,99,2,5,4), 99)
```

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/na_if.html

If you make the 99 values into NA, then you can compute whatever without it messing up the calculation. You can also simply remove NA values or 99...